Use condition filter after with() or load() Laravel Eloquent
Imagine we have a Facture and Item model in a one-to-many relationship. I'm using $facture->items() or $facture->load('items') and it works perfectly. However, when I need to use a condition on items like where('items.price', 30), I have no idea how to do it without DB::. Actually, I tried to use leftJoin(), because it has a condition on the right side of the relation, but this solution couldn't help me.

Depending on what you want to do, you have different options:

Query Item's of price 30 of this Facture

$facture->items()->where('price', 30);


Load Item's of price 30 of one or multiple Facture's

$factures->load(['items' => fn ($query) => $query->where('price', 30)]);


Load only Facture's that have at least one Item of price = 30

Facture::query()->whereHas('items', fn (Builder $query) => $query->where('price', 30));


Load only Facture's that have at least one Item of price = 30, but also load only those items

Facture::query()
  ->with(['items' => fn ($query) => $query->where('price', 30)])
  ->whereHas('items', fn (Builder $query) => $query->where('price', 30));


it seems this is a good use case for the whereRelation method,
you could do something like this in your query builder:
->whereRelation('items', 'price', '=', 30)
This will effectively return only the Factures that have items which prices are 30.
reference: https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.html#method_whereRelation
